# Fitnesse Slim runner cannot load .net 5 assembly: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018)

Tags: .net-core, .net-5, fitnesse-slim, fitsharp

Running a test in Fitnesse gives:

> Could not complete testing: fitnesse.slim.SlimError: Error SLiM server
> died before Header Message could be read.

When using Slim RunnerW.exe to debug my test I get an exception:

> `System.BadImageFormatException`: Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///c:\path\assemby.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module
> was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I used ProcessExplorer to check and RunnerW.exe was running in 64bit mode. My code is compiled with "Any CPU", the only difference with another working project is that it is a .net 5 (core) project using FitSharp 2.8.2.1 NuGet package.

After enabling the FusionLog it was clear that it could not load my main test assembly. This is part of the log:

```
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/path/assembly.exe.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\path\assembly.exe
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131018.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.
```

I think it is trying to load a .Net 5 assembly into a .Net 4 process?

Any ideas how to resolve this? I thought of adding an app.config file and specifying a runtime, but I'm not sure, it may just be a rabbit hole since it seems we need to be mixing frameworks here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that finally got me up and running:

1: Do not reference the executable (file ending with `.exe`) but refer to the `.dll` instead. No matter how it is compiled, trying to load the the .exe file as an assembly will always throw a `System.BadImageFormatException`.

2: Fish the .Net Core versions of `Runner.exe` and `RunnerW.exe` (and their dependencies) out of the NuGet package and use those instead of the older SLIM .Net runners (if you are migrating). `FusionLog` does absolutely nothing with .Net Core, so if there is any logging going on then you know that the process is not running .Net Core.

3: If you got the FitSharp projects from [GitHub](https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp) and are linking to the projects instead of using NuGet, then remove the post build actions to copy the files. Instead go to your test project `Dependencies` -> `Projects` -> `fit` open Properties (F4) and set the options `Reference Output Assembly`, `Copy Local` and `Copy Local Sattelite Assemblies` to Yes. Do the same for the FitSharp and Runner projects.